# JSON file loads to Cassandra 3.0.10

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is it possible to load an entire JSON file to Cassandra table? My table schema has been defined with one key field and a map field. My input json file(json_input.dat) looks like this

```
{"id": 123, "map_value": {"name":"aaa","address":"xyz","phone":"123-345-5678"}},{"id": 456, "map_value": {"name":"bbb","address":"zzz","phone":"523-645-5678"}}
```

I tried couple of things

1.) Insert from the above json file using COPY command - this completely didnt work
2.) Directly gave the same text in insert query - only the first record was inserted and the second record was skipped

Is it possible to insert a json document with multiple records in one shot to a cassandra table? Or should I write some custom code to fetch each record from the json file and do an insert?

I have created another table with one key field as decimal and instead of map type, used blob datatype. I tried giving blob datatype so as to ensure nested json string can be inserted to a column. Below is the insert query I tried

```
insert into tbl_jsonTest json '{"id": 123, "map_value": {"name":"aaa","address":"xyz","phone":"123-345-5678"}}';
```

and I am getting the following exception

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Error decoding JSON value for map_value: Value '{"name":"aaa","address":"xyz","phone":"123-345-5678"}' is not a valid blob representation: String representation of blob is missing 0x prefix
```

My table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_jsonTest ( 
    id decimal PRIMARY KEY, 
    map_value map<text, text> 
);
```

Can someone please guide me regarding the above questions. Am I missing something? Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your table schema ?

Comment: Not it's not possible to load entire json, possible with csv

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Below is my table schema CREATE TABLE tbl_jsonTest (
    id decimal PRIMARY KEY,
    map_value map<text, text>
 ). Can you please provide pointers for the blob datatype for map_value?